# re.search does not return match for some strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use re.search to extract patterns from strings with examples as follows:

"<2",  "<20.000"

```
import re
re.search('[0-9]*[\.][0-9]*','<20.000')[0]

'20.000'

re.search('[0-9]*[\.]*[0-9]*','<20.000')[0]

''

re.search('[0-9]*[\.][0-9]*','<2')[0]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

re.search('[0-9]*[\.]*[0-9]*','<2')[0]

''
```

I would have thought that the expression would work in the second case with the [\.]* for "20.000".  I also would have thought it would work for "<2", but both return blank strings.  I don't understand why it works for "20.000" with [\.] though.

Answer (score 3):

`*` matches the preceding pattern any number of times, including zero. So `[0-9]*[\.]*[0-9]*` matches zero digits followed by zero dots followed by zero digits, which allows it to match the zero-length string before `<`.

The version without `*` after `[\.]` requires a `.` in the match, so it can't match an empty string.

By the way, it's not necessary to escape `.` when it's inside `[]`. So you can write either `[.]` or `\.`, you don't need both.

Comment: Thanks!  After realizing what you said, I found '[0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*' to be the correct regex for what I'm trying to match.

Comment: You may want to do `r'[0-9]+[.]{0,1}[0-9]*'` just so that it does not match with 20..00 by mistake

Comment: @spizwhiz `{0,1}` can be simplified to `?` and `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`. Also, remember to use a raw string when writing regular expressions.